# laravel 5.3 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

(SOLVED) Thanks..

I just want to make a new view called "tambah.blade.php" and the controller is "JurnalController.php" with method "tambahJurnal", but it show an error. What's wrong with my route?

Here is my form:

```
<h1>Tambah Jurnal</h1>

 <form method="post" class="tambahJurnal" action="{{ route('tambah') }}" >
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="">
     No jurnal
     <input type="text" name="no_jurnal" value="">
   </div>

   <div class="">
     Tgl Jurnal
     <input type="date" name="tgl_jurnal" value="">
   </div>

   <div class="">
     Keterangan
     <input type="textarea" name="keterangan" value="">
   </div>

   <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

And here is my method in JurnalController:

```
public function tambahJurnal(Request $request){

  $jurnal = new Jurnals;
  $jurnal->no_jurnal = $request->no_jurnal;
  $jurnal->tgl_jurnal = $request->tgl_jurnal;
  $jurnal->keterangan = $request->keterangan;

  $jurnal->save();
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::post('/tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal');
```

And it show an error like this:
[enter image description here](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-CblaBMVGbyI/WNXg9Rm7oMI/AAAAAAAACCs/WkQV1KlvvnQMetYUWwZrm9t8Pk4KYT_twCLcB/s640/Capture.PNG)

Comment: Which url you are using to get this page ?

Comment: I use this one http://localhost:8000/tambah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## #1. Add this route in your route file.

`Route::get('/tambah', function()
{
    return view('tambah');
});`

## #2. change in `tambah.blade.php` file

`<form method="post" class="tambahJurnal" action="{{ route('tambah') }}" >`

to

`<form method="post" class="tambahJurnal" action="{{ url('tambah') }}" >`

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works.. So, in this case, I just need to change the route

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a route for the `POST` method with this line:

`Route::post('/tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal');`

But then, you're trying to perform a `GET` request with your browser on that URL. That's why you're getting that error.

Try adding this line as well:

`Route::get('/tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal');`

Answer (score 0):

You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

```
<h1>Tambah Jurnal</h1>

 <form method="post" class="tambahJurnal" action="{{ url('tambah') }}" >
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <div class="">
     No jurnal
     <input type="text" name="no_jurnal" value="">
   </div>

   <div class="">
     Tgl Jurnal
     <input type="date" name="tgl_jurnal" value="">
   </div>

   <div class="">
     Keterangan
     <input type="textarea" name="keterangan" value="">
   </div>

   <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try in form   action ="/tambah"
try with 
Route::any('/tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal');
first then if it works fine you can change to
Route::post('/tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal');

any will work for get post put ....

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Route::post('/tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal');
```

to

```
Route::post('tambah', 'JurnalController@tambahJurnal')->name('tambah');
```

and use blade `Form`

```
<h1>Tambah Jurnal</h1>

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'tambah','method' => 'POST','class' => 'tambahJurnal']) !!}
   <div class="">
     No jurnal
     <input type="text" name="no_jurnal" value="">
   </div>

   <div class="">
     Tgl Jurnal
     <input type="date" name="tgl_jurnal" value="">
   </div>

   <div class="">
     Keterangan
     <input type="textarea" name="keterangan" value="">
   </div>

   <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Advantage of using blade `Form` is , you don't explicitly need to specify `{{ csrf_field() }}`, blade injects `csrf token` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add route to show view

```
 Route::get('/tambah', 'JurnalController@index');
```

And add index method to your controller

```
 public function index(){
   return view("tambah");
 }
```

Also add `/`

```
 action="{{ route('/tambah') }}"
```

Sometimes it happened that you are in `/tambah` and trying to post url becomes `/tambah/tambah`